# Rephrasing "A are what is B" to "A are what are B"?

Tags: tenses

I see sentences like

> They are what is remembered.
>
> More troops are what is going to be needed.

And got me wonderin': Can I rephrase them this way?

> They are what are remembered.
>
> More troops are what are going to be needed.

Which way is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest avoiding all of the forms “X is what is needed”, “X are what is needed” and “X are what are needed”.  Instead, write “X is needed” (if X is singular) or “X are needed” (if X is plural), or go from passive forms to active: “We need X”.  If you must aver that X is the only thing or the precise thing that's needed, write  “X is all we need” or “Precisely X is all we need” or  “We just need X” etc.  (Use *are* in place of *is* where appropriate.)

Answer (score 0):

**It is always better to use active voice in sentences rather than using passive voice. The first sentence can be written as " They are what we remember." and the second sentence as "We/they(whatever it may be) are going to need more troops." So what is your opinion for this answer?**

Comment: It is not always better, @Barbie. Your second sentence above is passive, for example, and it would not be improved by recasting it in the active.

Answer (score -1):

> They are what is remembered

Is correct

I would rephrase the other too:

> More troops are what will be needed